# Token validation and pattern matching before server call

Tags: jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I want to check what kind of pattern the user is typing and based on that i want to make a server call. Could someone help here?

Here is what i have :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search_frwId").tokenInput("http://some rest service here", {
        theme: "facebook",
        queryParam : "param"
    });
});
```

Comment: This sort of activity would generally be done on the web server. Can you clarify - do you wish to change the `http://some rest service here` address depending on the pattern the user is typing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to pass a function as the first parameter of the setup (in place of a static URL.) If you can get user-input through jQuery, then you may be best to create a custom function to pattern match and generate the relevent URL string.

i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search_frwId").tokenInput(getMyRestServer, {
        theme: "facebook",
        queryParam : "param"
    });
});

function getMyRestServer(){
    var userinput = $("#search_frwId-input-facebook-theme").attr('value');
    // or if Jquery 2.x then use
    //  var userinput = $("#search_frwId-input-facebook-theme").prop('value');
    var url = "";

    //Do Magic Pattern Matching here

    return url;
}
```

You need to pass the function in there, not its evaluation

Comment: Its invoked only once on document load but not after that. any idea ?

Comment: @Yahiya - wait, thought I had it, but no. No, as far as I can see, it should call the function every time, whether the results are cached or not. What plugin version are you using/are you able to link to a demo, or set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi Chris...thanks. Your code worked with a small change. I've changed getMyRestServer() to getMyRestServer.

Comment: *Facepalm* Good spot - sorry.

Comment: somehow am not able to get the value of the search text box with var query = $(".token-input-input-token").text(); or var query = $("#seach_id").val(); any idea ?

Comment: @Yahiya Try `$(".token-input-input-token").('input').val()`? I think that might be it - but don't have a set up to debug with at the moment. If that doesn't do it - have a look at the code with Firebug/Chrome Inspector or something, and try and work out the exact jQuery - the input is wrapped inside a list and all sorts of other things!

Comment: tried for half a day... no use..dint get any solution yet.

Comment: Are you able to share a link to your page?

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle - you need to use `var userinput = $("#token-input-demo-input-facebook-theme").attr('value');`

Comment: (Or `$("#search_frwId-input-facebook-theme").attr('value');` if the id of you token input is the same as what you put in the original question.)

Comment: getting value as undefined...i tried in it this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HL8HF/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris. attr('value') dint work for me but i tried prop('value') and it worked. May be because i am using Jquery 2.x. Anyways, thanks a lot for your help... Now i am gonna start pattern matching using that userinput and call the appropriate rest service.